# Media has stopped working the way it should

Tags: codenameone

I have an app which I made over two years ago which has a list of videos. When one of the list buttons is clicked, the media played full screen. This was working perfectly OK on Android (I have't tried other platforms) until I resubmitted it to the build server on 31-07-2016. After this I noticed that the videos were no longer working full screen.
This month, I resubmitted the app to the build server and now there are a couple of things that don't work. The most noticeable feature is that the video is stretched in portrait mode to fill the form (even without setFullScreen()). The other issue I have noticed is that if I click the back button and play another video, I get the new video and the old video still playing at the side / corner of the screen. I have tried pause() and cleanup() but they seem to have no effect. I have tried adding the Media directly to a Container and using MediaPlayer and found the same issues with both.

```
    try {
        ((com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout) getLayout()).setCenterBehavior(com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER_ABSOLUTE);
        Media media = createMedia(currentExternalContent.getIs(), "video/m4v");
        Component videoComponent = media.getVideoComponent();
        Container videoContainer = new Container(new com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout());
        videoContainer.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, videoComponent);
        addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, videoContainer);
        revalidate();
        media.play();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Dialog.show("Catch", ex.getMessage(), "OK", "Cancel"); // gives 'read failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)'
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please file issues on those in github http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/ . We made some changes to media and some more are landing today so they might resolve this